# Is it better to use .delegate() performance wise?

Tags: javascript, jquery

One of the developers I work with began to write all his code this way:

```
$('.toggles').delegate('input', 'click', function() { 
   // do something  
});
```

vs:

```
$('.toggles').click(function() { 
   // do something  
});
```

Are there any performance benefits to doing this?

Comment: There can be depending on how many elements you would be putting handlers on if done individuallly.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) has been superseded by the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Comment: Don't use either? http://api.jquery.com/on/ could replace both of the above statements

Comment: These don't do the EXACT same thing. First one only listens to clicks on input elements

Comment: As sissonb noted, those examples are not exactly the same. Personally I would think that the second method is faster as you're attaching an event listener directly to an element (or elements sharing a class), while .delegate() has to search the DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`delegate()` is superseded as of jQuery 1.7.

Use `.on()` instead.

---

`.on()` has excellent performance benchmarks. And covers your `.click()` needs as well as needed

Comment: ...and covers your `.click()` needs as well as needed.

Comment: I don't see it listed as deprecated, although it has been superseded by `on`: http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: But the performance question still applies - are you binding to all clicks on a certain object, or listening for clicks on that object and its children, and seeing if they match another selector?  Which version of on() you use still matters.

Comment: Yeah, it probably won't be deprecated, since all valid calls to delegate() can easily be mapped to a corresponding call of on()

Comment: @JustinEthier: Thanks, answer modified.

Comment: @JustinEthier Truth speaks his name. If you examine the jQuery source, you will see that `.bind()`, `.live()` and `.delegate()` all reference `.on()`. As a matter of fact, `.click()` also references `.on('click')`, so if you want to save some function calls, might as well call `.on()` directly.

Comment: @Nix - I have examined the source code :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743504/is-it-better-to-use-delegate-performance-wise/9743618#9743618

Comment: @JustinEthier My bad. It's just a matter of semantics, though. While using any of the "old" methods might still work, behind the scenes it's just `.on()`. The way I see it, they're in limbo and in line for being left out of the code altogether (at least I hope so).

Comment: @Nix Care to move this discussion to chat? To prevent clutter and notifications on my side? :P

Comment: @JustinEthier Care to move this discussion to chat? To prevent clutter and notifications on my side? :P

Answer (score 2):

As frenchie stated, in the latest version of jQuery, both functions end up mapping to [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

In the jQuery code, you can see that delegate is really just a wrapper for `on`:

```
delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );
},
```

Then, when jQuery binds `click` (as well as other events) it calls into `on` as well:

```
jQuery.each( ("... click ... ").split(" "), function( i, name ) {

// Handle event binding
jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
    if ( fn == null ) {
        fn = data;
        data = null;
    }

    return arguments.length > 0 ?
        this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
        this.trigger( name );
};
...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and in fact, there's an even better way to do it, with **.on()**: take a look at [this](http://codebetter.com/johnpetersen/2011/11/04/jquery-1-7-released-event-handling-in-a-better-simplified-and-consolidated-way/)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you can use `.on()`. As far as your question is concerned, `.on()` and also `.delegate()` for that matter has better performance than binding events to the target directly. That is because these binders listens to an element which is higher in the DOM tree and then checks the target, as the pool of your targets increases `.on()` and `.delegate()` will surely give you performance benefit.

And in general, they will always be more efficient.

Comment: `.delegate()` is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that if all the items of class "toggles" are present when that binding is made, that delegate() would be less efficient.  It binds to everything of class "toggles", and then, when one of those elements is clicked, checks to see if the actual DOM object being clicked is an input.

click(), on the other hand, is a shortcut for bind(), which binds directly to everything of class "toggle" and always triggers when that DOM item is clicked.

The only reason to use delegate() would be if inputs are added inside items of class "toggle" after the binding is made.

This also applies to using different overloads of on(), which replaces delegate() and bind() (and by replacing bind, also replaces click()).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Using `.delegate` will reduce the number of event handlers.

Suppose you have a table in your page and you want to attach click handler to each `<td>`.
Instead of attaching event handler to individual `<td>`s attach it to the table:

```
$("#myTable").delegate("click", "td", function() {
    //do some thing on click of td
});
```

When you click on the `<td>` the event will bubble up to the table. Here by using delegate we can reduced the number of event handlers, which improves the performance.

delegate is deprecated in latest version of jQuery use `.on` instead it works like delegate.

Answer (score 0):

There's another addition that you should be aware of concerning the use of on (delegate in older versions) vs click:

if you do this :

```
 $("a").click(function() {  
  alert("Click on link detected");  
  $(this).after("<a href='#'>New link</a>");  
});
```

your new link will not be attached to the "a" click handler even though it should because it is a link.

however if you use on :

```
$("a").on("click", function(event){  
   $(this).after("<a href='#'>Nouveau lien</a>");  
});
```

with this the new link responds to the click event with the click handler.